# @RepositoryRestResource entity fields null during add new entity with curl POST

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

This is a spring-boot application and I've got couple of `@Entity`s and their respective `@RepositoryRestResource`s. `App` is parent and `History` is child in the DB. When I'm trying to add new record to History (using POST), I can't figure out why `version` and `tag` are null in the response.

These fields are `null` in DB too. Debugging realized the request is not deserialized properly. Anyone seen this issue before?

Suspecting [this](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/search?q=%22databind%232023%22&unscoped_q=%22databind%232023%22) fix to be the cause, can't really confirm because downgrading the jackson version didn't help. Full application is [here](https://github.com/anandchakru/rest-repo-jpa/tree/f5e5f5871a1265c95a851fce084ddc81282c97f2).

```
$ curl -d '{"app":{"appId":1,"name":"test2"},"version":"v13","tag:"tagtest1"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8080/repo/history
```

**Response :**

```
{
  "version" : null,
  "tag" : null,
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/repo/history/1"
    },
    "history" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/repo/history/1"
    },
    "app" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/repo/history/1/app"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that it's missing close brackets on curl command: $ curl -d '{"app":{"appId":1,"name":"test2"},"version":"v13","tag" :"tagtest"}'  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8080/repo/history

Comment: that's just a typo, issue exists with the close } braces also

Comment: OK let me check your repo, I'm just looking from my phone.. :)

Comment: Could you add in @RepositoryRestResources(collectionResourceRel = "app",...)

Comment: `collectionResourceRel` didn't help..

Answer (score 0):

I cloned your repository, and it's working but a couple of things, I'm not sure how you can send directly ManyToOne Object because that is the mistake in order to map it. because if you send the below body, it will be mapped version and tag but the app JSON object no, so you have to research about how to pass a JSON Object with realtionship Many to one. You need to take a look this answer [Save child objects automatically using JPA Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927091/save-child-objects-automatically-using-jpa-hibernate)

```
{
    "version":"v13",
    "tag":"tagtest1",
    "app":{
        "appId": 1, 
        "name":"test112"
    }
}
```