# How to reference children id when save parent in spring data

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a Many to One relationship. 
Is it possible to select the children database id based on particular column prior saving the parent?

Here is my code:

```
public class Employee {
    @AssociationOverrides({@AssociationOverride(name = "staffNumber"), @AssociationOverride(name = "staffNumber"),
                           @AssociationOverride(name = "homeAddress", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "homeAddress")),
                           @AssociationOverride(name = "officeAddress", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "officeAddress"))})
    @EmbeddedId
    private EmployeeId id;
}

@Data
@Embeddable
public class EmployeeId {

    @Column(name = "staffNumber")
    private String staffNumber;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address homeAddress;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address officeAddress;

}

@Data
public class Address {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Columnn(name="country")
    private String country;

    @Column(name="city")
    private String city;
}

public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, EmployeeId> {}
```

Is it possible to do save employee

```
employeeRepository.save(employee);
```

without having to select

```
 addressRepository.findAddressByCity(city)
```

where I only have Address without the id (id = 0), but in the database there's a City("New York", with id 2 and "San Fransisco" with id 1)

```
Employee: { 
   EmployeeId: { 
     staffNumber: "123", 
     homeAddress: {id:0, country: null, city: "New York"}, 
     officeAddress:{id:0, country: null, city: "San Fransisco"}
   }
}
```

Comment: You want to select child table record based on child table column name ? Please specify more details exactly what you want.

Comment: I would like to save the parent along with the children.
I would like to do `employeeRepository.save(employee);` without having to search what is the Address id first with a result in db as below
```
Employee: { 
   EmployeeId: { 
     staffNumber: "123", 
     homeAddress: id:2, --> 2 is the Address table id
     officeAddress: id:1 --> 1 is the Address table id
   }
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to save new employee with new address?

Comment: Please check this [hibernate relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927091/save-child-objects-automatically-using-jpa-hibernate)

Comment: Is it possible to save the child without knowing the child's id first? But I know some of the child's columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save a child record without knowing the child primary id, but make sure the result should be unique if you fetching other than the primary key column.

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.setStaffNumber("123);
```

You can find an address by other columns also like below.

```
Address officeAddress = addressRepository.findAddressByCity(city); // Office Address
Address homeAddress = addressRepository.findAddressByCity(city); // Home Address

// Setting child objects in parent object
employee.setHomeAddress(homeAddress);
employee.setOfficeAddress(officeAddress);
```

And finally, save the parent object it will save employee detail with home and office address.

```
employeeRepository.save(employee);
```

Comment: Thanks Naresh.
I was hoping that I don't have to do `findAddressByCity` first to set the children.
I was hoping there's some annotation in Adrress to query maybe something like `@Query("SELECT id FROM Address WHERE city =$")`