# Hibernate @OneToMany: PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, one-to-many

I have two dtos and corresponding dao interfaces which extend JpaRepository

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SequenceGenerator(name = "parentSequence", sequenceName = "parent_id_seq",
        allocationSize = 1)
public class ParentDto implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "parentSequence")
    private Long id;
    
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", targetEntity = Child.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<ChildDto> children;
}


@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@SequenceGenerator(name="childSequence", sequenceName = "child_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
@Table(name = "child")
public class ChildDto {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "childSequence")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false)
    private ParentDto parent;
}

public interface ParentDao extends JpaRepository<ParentDto, Long> {
}
public interface ChildDao extends JpaRepository<ChildDto, Long> {
}
```

I have the next request to save mapped to property `request` (ids should be generated by DB)

> {
> "parent": {
> "name": "Bob",
> "children": [{
> "name": "Bob2"
> }]
> } }

Executing `parentDao.save(request);` and getting exception

> Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into
> child (id, name, parent_id) values (1, "Bob2", NULL) was aborted:
> ERROR: null value in column "parent_id" violates not-null constraint
> Detail: Failing row contains (1, "Bob2", NULL).  Call getNextException
> to see other errors in the batch. Caused by:
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column
> "parent_id" violates not-null constraint   Detail: Failing row
> contains (1, "Bob2", NULL).

Comment: Have a look at this, most probably related, question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927091/save-child-objects-automatically-using-jpa-hibernate

Answer (score 0):

You are cascading persistence from the parent to the child, but the child has no parent. As well as adding a child to the parent make sure you also set the parent on the child. It's important to keep them in sync when declaring bidirectional relationships

```
child.setParent(parent);
```

Comment: any other ideas? I have the same problem and my child has a reference to own parent. And it's also doest work

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but for new people wondering, the answer by [@johnnynutts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73649545/1153088) is actually correct. There are multiple ways to implement a `@OneToMany` relationship in hibernate. As described in detail by [a post from Vlad Mihalcea](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/), these ways are:

- Unidirectional @OneToMany
- Unidirectional @OneToMany with @JoinColumn
- Bidirectional @OneToMany (which is the one used in the question's example)

If you decide to implement the `Bidirectional` method, then you need keep both connection in sync (update both parent & child) or else you'll get the error on saving.